# Send signal to vibrate a Restaurant buzzer via web based app to a PC

Tags: programming, wifi

I'm new to Arduino, I want to create a restaurant buzzer using Arduino and it should turn on/off via web based interface. It will be locally connected only.

Is it possible to send a signal with the mac address of the master transmitter pc to vibrate the buzzer?

What are the materials should I need? Suggestions or any tips is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For anything that required TPC/IP, a better option is  nodeMCU (ESP8266). And for simply turning on a buzzer, MQTT is way easier that anything involving a web server. You can send the mac address, the ip address or whatever ID you choose .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a webserver, a defined interface for the client to connect to and a buzzer you can make some noise with.

Because you want to do it over WIFI, an Arduino is probably not the best choice.  As 'Look Alterno' says you might be better with an ESP8266 based device, because that has inbuilt WIFI.  I would suggest a Wemos D1, its an ESP8266 12 with a power supply and 2.54 pitch connectors, which means its easy to use with things.
[image]

Now you can program an ESP8266 using LUA, but I really wouldn't try that. Also if you do that you won't get any help on this forum.  Use the Arduino IDE and program it in the same language as an Arduino (You will need to download support for the ESP via the Board Manager in the IDE).  There is an example called "Advanced Web Server", done by Majenko on here, that will suit your needs.  You just need to change the root handler to activate the buzzer for n seconds and then return HTTP code 200.

Then your client just needs to connect to the root page of the webserver and the buzzer will sound.  You don't say how many clients will use this, but this will allow 5 simultaneous clients, if you need more that can be achieved easily.

You can then expand this to identify which client sounded the buzzer.

As to keeping it local, use the firewall on your router.

Comment: I strongly don't recommend LUA. It's a very beautiful language that I wish I can use, but in a bigger and more powerfull machine. I ran a Webserver under LUA, but crashed all the time. ESP8266 ***can*** run a light Webserver under C, but not even think about sending a 100KB javascript file thru it.

Comment: Also, ESP8266 have an upper limit of 5 TCP/IP connections at the same time. While sending a buzz is short and light, you will not able to manage a worst case scenario.

Comment: I want ESP8266 to connect my web site locally, not to connect in ESP8266. So my PC will act as the webserver and if ES8266 reads something to the code that will send signal to buzz.

Comment: OK.  I didn't get that from the question.  Strangely the solution is the same :)  The easiest way of connecting from your PC to the ESP is to use WIFI and run a webserver on the ESP that the PC talks to.  This gets around the 5 connection limit.  You could go to the effort of writing a serial client for your PC that sent the messages when the webserver got a request, but that's not going to be easy.  You are also going to have to write serial code for the ESP to parse the messages.  Its a lot of effort.  Does using WIFI from PC to ESP fit in with your plan?